# Recreate FRM files ( structure files )

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I was moving files around and for some reason all frm files are now empty, how can I recreate them ? most of the tables are myisam but a few are innodb.

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: Even if you only have the table definitions, you could re-create them

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM tables are gone, InnoDB - you can [recover from the dictionary](https://twindb.com/recover-table-structure-from-innodb-dictionary/)

Comment: how can they be gone if all data is still there ?

Comment: We are talking about table structure, ain't we?

Comment: sure, but is it really this faulty, I mean, if you lose a 10k file all your data is gone

Comment: I saw some research paper on recovery frm files from a raw disk image. It's based on signatures lookup. Authors claim to implement it in a tool , but I never tested it. http://www.jofcis.com/publishedpapers/2015_11_15_5415_5423.pdf

Comment: And yes, MyISAM is fragile. All important data should be in innodb